# Google Play Services - Linked app Authorization automatic

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games, android-app-signing

I've released a game on the Google Play Store not too long ago. It makes use of Google Play Services, so it has a linked app in the Google Play Developer Console with the SHA1 of its production keystore.

However, now I'm also releasing that game on the Amazon Play Store. This store automatically changes the keystore certificate of the game, so that means that I'll need another linked app with a different SHA1 for this version of the app.

However, whenever I attempt to link another app in the Google Play Developers Console, it automatically gives me a Client ID without even asking me of my SHA1. It didn't do this when the Google Play Services were unpublished, but know it does.

I believe it's just using the SHA1 of the published Android version of the game for everything, so it automatically uses the SHA1 of that version.

Does anyone know of a way for me to manually enter my SHA1 and get a Client ID based on that? It'd be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add credentials to the API console project.  If you scroll down in the Game Details page in the Play Console, there is a link to the API console project (for example mine is called 'Minimal') [image]

If you click on that, it takes you to another console.  On the left menu there is a "Credentials" item.  Click that and you can view/edit/create all the clients for your game.